# Trailing return type for reference

Tags: c++, c++11, trailing-return-type

Consider the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {

public:
    using T = float;
    A(const T& x)
    {
        m_value = x;
    }

    T& value();

private:
    T m_value;
};

// A::T& A::value()
//  {
//      return m_value;
//  }

auto& A::value() -> T &
{
    return m_value;
}

int main()
{
    A a(10.0);
    std::cout << a.value() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When compile using C++11, I get the following error.

```
error: ‘value’ function with trailing return type has ‘auto&’ as its type rather than plain ‘auto’
   auto& A::value()->T &
                       ^
```

The equivalent code (the commented function) is working fine.
But I would like to use trailing return type.

Comment: Just do what the error suggests and write `auto A::value()->T &`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the trailing return type, you cannot have anything other than the `auto` specifier at the place where you would normally put the return type:

```
auto  A::value()->T &
//  ^ no '&' here
{
    return m_value;
}
```

The type you specified after the `->` is already a reference though, so no worries.